# Inject @Context fields using Guice's @Inject (into subresources)

Tags: java, glassfish, jersey, jax-rs, guice

I am currently developing a REST webservice using Jersey and Guice as a DI-container.

For handling the requests I am relying on a `GuiceServletContextListener` which is configured similar to the following:

```
bind(UserResource.class);
//Some other root-level resources for REST

serve("/rest/*").with(GuiceContainer.class);
```

As I have to deal with hierarchical data (One user should have their own items and it should be possible to access items of other users in the form of `/rest/user/[Username]/item`). For this, I am using Jersey's support for subresources.

For example, my `UserResource` contains the following method (`ItemResource.Factory` is a factory interface whose implementation is automatically provided by Guice's `FactoryModuleBuilder`):

```
@Inject
private ItemResource.Factory _itemResourceFactory;

@Path("/{username}/item")
public ItemResource getItems(@PathParam("username") String username) {
   User user = //...
   return this._itemResourceFactory.create(user);
}
```

`ItemResource` (the subresource) then again is implemented as a normal Jersey class based on the User passed in in the constructor.

However, my subresources need access to `@Context` fields (like `UriInfo` or `HttpServletRequest`), too. According to the Jersey documentation, `@Context` fields are not injected for subresources as their lifecycle is unknown (and the documentation seems to be true).

This is very unfortuante for me: I really need access to those values.
As a workaround, I am currently passing those values as additional constructor parameters to my subresources which I perceive as everything but comfortable.

Is there any possibility to tell Jersey to inject them anyway?

Nevertheless, even better would be if Guice itself was able to inject the `@Context` fields.
Simply swapping the `@Context` for `@Inject`, however, doesn't work as Guice has no registrations for types like `UriInfo` or `HttpServletRequest`.

Can I somehow create those mappings?
The problem is, that I don't know how to access the request specific values inside a Guice `Provider` implementation.
Are there maybe any helper methods to get access to the current instances of those Jersey objects so I can write the necessary providers?

Or are those implementations maybe already available somewhere out there?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood your problem. Can you post the code related to "passing those values as additional constructor parameters"?

You can inject the Context like this:

@Path("/{username}/item")
public ItemResource getItems(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @PathParam("username") String username) {

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could inject fields programmatically? Guice provides this through the Injector class:

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(...);
injector.injectMembers(someObjectToInject);
```

See http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Injections for more information on this topic.

Comment: No, my problem is how to register those objects with Guice (@Context objects are Jersey-specific and are usually injected using a Jersey-internal injector). Once registered in Guice, injecting them would be no problem (this is automatically done by the GuiceContainer).